# Asp.net Core 2 verifying that all dependencies have been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

A while ago I've decided to use SimpleInjector because of it's `Verify()` method that checks that all dependencies in the application have been registered correctly.

I would like to start using Microsoft's built-in dependency injection container instead. But I can't seem to find anything on how to verify that all dependencies have been registered.

I can't imagine that Microsoft's dependency injection system wouldn't provide me a way to validate my dependencies. So I must be missing something.

Comment: Unit tests on your startup. Or functional tests to see if you can correctly resolve your services. Don't think there's anything built in unfortunately!

Comment: *“I can't imagine that Microsoft's dependency injection system wouldn't provide me a way to validate my dependencies.”* – But that’s exactly what it is. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection is a very simple dependency injection container which by design does not have many advanced features. If you require something like that, then you can always switch to a different dependency injection container.